# Annoying Lock On switch

Tags: nioh

Can I change the Lock On switching? Using the keyboard and mouse it's really annoying when fighting more than one enemy.

Answer (score 1):

The switching of lock on targets is notoriously sensitive or unintuitive using a mouse (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nioh/comments/7ks29s/is_there_anyway_to_stop_lockon_from_randomly/) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/485510/discussions/0/1488866813762322374/), for example).

**You can turn off Lock On by pressing** <kbd>F</kbd>, unless it's mapped differently (obviously). Check your *Key Configuration* under *Controls* in the *System Menu* to be sure.

Unfortunately, the key-binding for '*Switch Lock-on Target to the Left/Right*' seems to be fixed to '*Move Camera Left/Right*', and changing that is not even an option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately even [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/363162) doesn't actually fix anything. The game automatically switches to whatever is to your Right, so if an enemy is to your right, you will likely lock onto them after locking onto your enemy in front of you, then it will also likely switch back and forth. This is just bad design that cannot actually be corrected completely (even the so called fixes people come with still ultimately do not actually fix the issue, just make one aspect of it, related to the facing direction of your character, and not the actual auto lock switching.

It's very likely just an oversight like not having keyboard and mouse prompts for a long time (they have them now lol).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: its a comment that states that the provided solution doesn't work